# How to add class to div based on radio button selected in it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have written html like below lines of code.

```
<div class="form-group">

    <div class="i-checks">
       <label class="col-sm-6 control-label"> 
         <div class="iradio_square-green" style="position: relative;">
         <input type="radio" value="name" name="checkchoice" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
         <ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0;"></ins>
         </div>
         Name
        </label>
     </div>

     <div class="i-checks">
       <label class="col-sm-6 control-label"> 
         <div class="iradio_square-green" style="position: relative;">
         <input type="radio" value="rollno" name="checkchoice" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
         <ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0;"></ins>
         </div>
         Roll No
        </label>
     </div>

</div>
```

Now I want that if anyone select any radio button then in the corresponding div
`<div class="iradio_square-green" style="position: relative;">` the class "checked" should be appended like `<div class="iradio_square-green checked" style="position: relative;">`

I have tried

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(':radio').change(function () {
    $(':radio[name=' + this.name + ']').parent().removeClass('checked');
    $(this).parent().addClass('checked');
  });
});​
```

It is not working

Comment: SO is not a free coding service - so show us what you have tried.

Comment: show your code after that will help you...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with pure CSS, no need for JS (if styling is your only aim)

CSS:

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ div {
    some styles....
}
```

Ideally you will use class names and not tag names for the above.